# How to enable WinZip setting via SCCM

Tags: windows-domain, shell-extensions, winzip, sccm

I have deployed a pre-configured WinZip MSI without the shell extensions option due to Windows Explorer crashes.

However is there a way to apply a network setting via SCCM, or Group Policy to enable shell extensions for WinZip through the domain?

I hope this is clear!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have introduced a GP mechanism for declaring these defaults in Win 8 to accommodate this type of scenario. The basic idea is to have an xml file that maps programs to the file type/protocol that they should be the default for.

You can create your XML file or export it from a machine using DISM:

> Export the default application association settings from the test
>   computer to an .xml file on a network share or USB drive. For example,
>   at a command prompt type the following command:
>
> ```
> Dism /Online /Export-DefaultAppAssociations:\\Server\Share\AppAssoc.xml
> ```
>
> Import the .xml file that has the default application association
>   settings to the Windows image. For example, at the command prompt type
>   the following command:
>
> ```
> Dism.exe /Image:C:\test\offline /Import-DefaultAppAssociations:\\Server\Share\AppAssoc.xml
> ```

Source [Export or Import Default Application Associations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825038.aspx)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). 
You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).
I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.